# Cordova Paytm plugin integration

Tags: angularjs, cordova, plugins, ionic-framework, paytm

I integrated the cordova paytm plugin in our ionic app.It is working fine. But after successful payment transaction, it is redirecting to specified call back url. it is not coming back to the app. If callback url is not specified, it is redirecting to error page.I want to get back to app after payment transaction.How i can get the response to the app itself ?

Plugin : http://github.com/samyam-a/PayTM-PhoneGap-Plugin

Please help me to sort out this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Did you solve it? Share your answer if you solved it. That may help others

Comment: Hi , can you please tell me where did you get these parameters :-

GENERATE_URL=<Checksum Generation URL> --variable VERIFY_URL=<Checksum Validation Url> --variable MERCHANT_ID=<MerchantID> --variable INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID=<IndustryType> --variable WEBSITE=<WAPWebsiteName>

Comment: Did you solve it? Share your answer if you solved it. That may help others